# Automatic rolling / scrolling text when text in listbox item is long

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, expression-blend-4

Suppose I have a long text in a listbox item which can not fit in the screen. I want such text to be automatically rolling so that the user can see the text completely. How can I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your listbox's item data template you could use a TextBlock to display your text and set the TextWrapping property on it to Wrap:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyItemText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="150" />
```

Here's an article on wrapping text and also using line breaks:
http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/10/09/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-58-text-wrapping-and-line-breaks-in-textblocks.aspx